# How can I check if an array contains a 3 next to a 3?

Tags: python, function, loops, for-loop

I need to find if an array of ints contains a 3 next to a 3.

This is the code I currently have:

```
def has_33(nums):
  for i in nums:
    if i== 3:
      if abs(nums[i]-nums[i+1:-1])==0:
        print(True)
      else:print(False)
    else:pass
```

It gives me the following error:

> nums[i+1] not in range

These are my test cases:

```
has_33([ 3, 1, 3])      # i want output true for this list
has_33([1, 3, 1, 3])    # true
has_33([1, 3, 2])       # false     
has_33([4, 2, 3, 3, 2]) # true
has_33([1, 3, 3, 1])    # true
```

I want to find the first 3 in the list. If another 3 is present in the list after the first 3 then I want to print true, otherwise I want to print false.

Comment: And what is your question/error?

Comment: Hey! and welcome to SO. In order for us to help you with your problem, it'll be helpful that you state your question and tell us the steps you've made in order to try and solve the problem. without that we don't have a lead to start and help you debug the problem.

Comment: It would be much more easy to test that by moving along the array and check if the number at position i and the number at position i + 1 are both 3. Requires one for and one if, linear cost

Comment: Does it matter if the 3s are next to each other in the array, or should you get `true` for any array which contains 3 twice regardless of whether or not they're next to each other? The question says they should be next to each other, but your test cases suggest the opposite. Please could you edit either the question or the test cases to clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to solve this

```
def has_33(array):
threes = [] #create an array to store threes
for x in array:
    if x == 3:
        threes.append(x) #if number is three, append it to array
        
if len(threes) > 1: #check if length of array is greater then 1
    return True
else:
    return False

print(has_33([1,3,8,3,3,5])) #returns True
print(has_33([1,3,8,2,1,5])) #returns False
```